# Looking for an example of stochastic processes with "very" different trajectories, but still modifications of each other

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Could anyone offere an example of two stochastic processes that are modifications of each other, i.e.

$P(A_t)=1\qquad \forall t\in [0,T]$,$\qquad$ with $A_t:=\{\omega\in\Omega:X_t=Y_t\}$,

and such that

$P(\omega\in\Omega: \mu(I_{\omega})>0)>0$, with $I_{\omega}:=\{t\in [0,T] : \omega \in A^c_t  \}$, and 
 where $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,T]$?

Let me give you a bit of context. I am trying to understand how different could be, in principle, the trajectories of two versions of the same process. So far, all I could find is the typical textbook example of a modification that is not indistinguishable, which is simple but not satisfactory as the trajectories only differ at one time.

My intuition (which could be wrong of course) is that a modification like the one above should exist, but I struggle to find a formal argument to prove it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

As $\mathbb{P}(A_t^c)=0$ for each $t \geq 0$, we have by Tonelli's theorem

$$\mathbb{E} \left( \int_0^{T} 1_{A_t^c} \, dt \right) = \int_0^{T} \mathbb{P}(A_t^c)=0,$$

and so

$$\int_0^{T} 1_{A_t^c} \, dt = 0 \quad \text{a.s.}$$

Since $1_{A_t^c}(\omega) = 1_{I_{\omega}}(t)$ this implies that

$$\int_0^T 1_{I_{\omega}}(t) \, dt=0 \quad \text{a.s.},$$

i.e. $\mu(I_{\omega})=0$ almost surely. This means that there doesn't exist a modification with "very different" sample paths.

Comment: This shows that there is no such *jointly measurable* process.

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker Yeah, right... but the OP needs in any case some measurability assumptions to ensure that all the objects he his talking about are well-defined.